# How/Where to define an App ID Prefixes in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-id

As a new iOS developer, I am trying to define "Bundle Seed ID" (App ID Prefix) for my app.

How/where is "Bundle Seed ID" (App ID Prefix)" defined in Xcode?

Please provide the step in details.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I thought App ID should be defined in Member Center.

Here's the link to create a new App ID https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleCreate.action

In this page, you can see "App ID Prefix", that is associated with your team.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, you means we cannot define by ourselves ?

Comment: !  Yes, he means.

Comment: Is App ID Prefix and Apple App Prefix same things?

Comment: @salvishahzad yes

Answer (score 113):

Here is the link 
https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/

Your **App ID Prefix** is the same as your **Team ID**.

You can also use this link to see it directly:
https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

[image]

Comment: This is not always the case,  iOS has two different types of App ID prefixes: a new kind that is your Team ID and an older-style that uses a ten digit alphanumeric string instead of your Team ID. If you have been writing apps for a long time, you may have a number of the older-style prefixes in place, but that would only be the case if you have created additional prefixes yourself (this was only possible prior to the introduction of iCloud in June

Comment: ughhh what in the heck!!

Answer (score 18):

Here is the link 
https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/

Your **App ID** Prefix is the same as your **Team ID**.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For Apps created after 2011 your App ID Prefix is your Team ID.  However, for apps created during 2011 or before, it is possible to have different App ID Prefixes.  To get a definitive answer go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle, click on your App ID and under Name you will see "Prefix" which will show the actual value of your App ID Prefix, whether it is the same as your Team ID or not.

Be sure to check this before setting up associated domains for universal linking, shared web credentials, handoff, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided are not completely accurate.  The application identifier prefix IS NOT necessarily the Team ID.  For older accounts, they can be different.  An easy way to find it is to look at the provisioning profile for the bundle ID you are interested in.

Look at the "ENTITLEMENTS" section and you will find the "application-identifier".  This will be the application identifier prefix and bundle ID you will use.  This may be different than the "com.apple.developer.team-identifier".