# Which "app-id" do I use for an App Clip's apple-itunes-app meta tag?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-id, apple-appclips

I'm following the [instructions to associate an App Clip with a website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/supporting_invocations_from_your_website_and_the_messages_app):

> `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, app-clip-bundle-id=appClipBundleID, app-clip-display=card">`

But I'm not sure what to put in the `app-id` because usually the App ID refers to the Team ID + bundle identifier (e.g. `ABCDE12345.com.example.MyApp`), but then it also says `myAppStoreID` which sounds different.

What goes in the `app-id` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `app-id` refers to the **App Store ID**, and not the **App ID**. This is clearly stated in [the more general documentation about Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners).

These identifiers are sometimes confusing because of conflicting names<sup>1</sup>, or wrong documentation<sup>2</sup>. Here's a comprehensive list that should hopefully clear up some confusion:

|  | Example values | Terms used by Apple | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Bundle ID** | [`com.example.MyApp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_an_app_clip_with_xcode), [`com.example.MyApp.Clip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website) | [`bundle ID`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id), [`Bundle ID (explicit)`](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) | User defined, typically in reverse domain name notation. |
| **Team ID** | [`ABCDE12345`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website), [`8XCUU22SN2`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-your-team/locate-your-team-id) | [`Team ID`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id), [`Team ID`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-your-team/locate-your-team-id) | Assigned by Apple. |
| **App ID Prefix** | [`ABCDE12345`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website) | [`App ID Prefix (Team ID)`](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) | Usually [same as **Team ID**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492119/how-where-to-define-an-app-id-prefixes-in-xcode). |
| **`$(AppIdentifierPrefix)`**<sup>2</sup> | [`ABCDE12345.`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id-for-app-clips) | [`$(AppIdentifierPrefix)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_an_app_clip_with_xcode) | The **App ID Prefix** followed by a `.` |
| **App ID** | [`ABCDE12345.com.example.MyApp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website) | [`app identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id), [`App ID`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id)<sup>1</sup>, [`explicit App ID`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id), [`app identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website) | The **`$(AppIdentifierPrefix)`** followed by the **Bundle ID**. |
| **wildcard App ID** | [`ABCDE12345.*`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id), [`ABCDE12345.com.example.*`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id), [`*`](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) | [`wildcard App ID`](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id) | Similar to the **App ID**, but with a wildcard (`*`) character. |
| **App Store ID** | [`1146562112`](https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app/1146562112) | [`app-id`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners), [`myAppStoreID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners), [`app ID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners)<sup>1</sup>, [`Apple ID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners) | Assigned by Apple. Used in [App Store URLs](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/safari/id1146562112). |

Footnotes:

1. Notice how even though **App ID** and **App Store ID** are clearly different values, they have both been referred to as `App ID` and `app ID`, respectively.
2. Note that this variable includes the trailing `.`. You can see this by [looking at a build’s environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project), or at the variable’s usage in the [Fruta app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui) (`$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.example.apple-samplecode.fruta`). There is only [one location](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/register-an-app-id-for-app-clips) that shows it doesn’t contain a `.`, but it contradicts itself in the same sentence. A [nearly identical paragraph](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_an_app_clip_with_xcode) correctly omits the `.`:

   > For example, if your full app’s app identifier is $(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.example.MyApp, the app identifier for your App Clip would be $(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.example.MyApp.Clip.